# Which BitBucket plugin do I need to use with IntellJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, plugins, bitbucket

I've looked at several instructions on how to use BitBucket with IntelliJ but one was from 2013 and another didn't mention any of the plugins that come up when I'm on Atlassian's site and search for BitBucket. So, I'm uncertain as to what I should use.

I found [this site](https://blog.johannfenech.com/?p=319) but it doesn't mention any of these plugins. Which is the most up to date?

When I search for "bitbucket" in IntelliJ's *Plugins → Marketplace* it shows this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any plugins to work with BitBucket repositories in IntelliJ:

- To create a project from your BitBucket repo, just copy the repo URL -- the one passed as argument to `git clone` when you click the [Clone] button in your BitBucket's repository page, and feed it to IntelliJ's *File → New → Project from Version Control → Git*
- To have IntelliJ recognize issue IDs in commit messages and the like, go to *Settings → Version Control → Issue Navigation* and configure a pattern and URL for your issue manager (ours is `[A-Z]+[0-9]*\-\d+` - `https://<our company>.atlassian.net/browse/$0` for JIRA issue IDs like "PRJ-1427").